# Apache Spark 2.3.1 with Hive metastore 3.1.0

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hive-metastore, hdp

We have upgraded HDP cluster to 3.1.1.3.0.1.0-187 and have discovered:

1. Hive has a new metastore location
2. Spark can't see Hive databases

In fact we see:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchDatabaseException: Database ... not found
```

Could you help me understanding what has happened and how to solve this?

**Update:**

Configuration:

> (spark.sql.warehouse.dir,/warehouse/tablespace/external/hive/)
>   (spark.admin.acls,)
>   (spark.yarn.dist.files,file:///opt/folder/config.yml,file:///opt/jdk1.8.0_172/jre/lib/security/cacerts)
>   (spark.history.kerberos.keytab,/etc/security/keytabs/spark.service.keytab)
>   (spark.io.compression.lz4.blockSize,128kb)
>   (spark.executor.extraJavaOptions,-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts)
>   (spark.history.fs.logDirectory,hdfs:///spark2-history/)
>   (spark.io.encryption.keygen.algorithm,HmacSHA1)
>   (spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold,26214400)
>   (spark.eventLog.enabled,true) (spark.shuffle.service.enabled,true)
>   (spark.driver.extraLibraryPath,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64)
>   (spark.ssl.keyStore,/etc/security/serverKeys/server-keystore.jks)
>   (spark.yarn.queue,default)
>   (spark.jars,file:/opt/folder/component-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)
>   (spark.ssl.enabled,true) (spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown,true)
>   (spark.shuffle.unsafe.file.output.buffer,5m)
>   (spark.yarn.historyServer.address,master2.env.project:18481)
>   (spark.ssl.trustStore,/etc/security/clientKeys/all.jks)
>   (spark.app.name,com.company.env.component.MyClass)
>   (spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars,/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/standalone-metastore/*)
>   (spark.io.encryption.keySizeBits,128) (spark.driver.memory,2g)
>   (spark.executor.instances,10)
>   (spark.history.kerberos.principal,spark/edge.env.project@ENV.PROJECT)
>   (spark.unsafe.sorter.spill.reader.buffer.size,1m)
>   (spark.ssl.keyPassword,*********(redacted))
>   (spark.ssl.keyStorePassword,*********(redacted))
>   (spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled,true)
>   (spark.shuffle.io.serverThreads,128)
>   (spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc,true)
>   (spark.submit.deployMode,client) (spark.sql.orc.char.enabled,true)
>   (spark.master,yarn) (spark.authenticate.enableSaslEncryption,true)
>   (spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval,7d) (spark.authenticate,true)
>   (spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge,90d)
>   (spark.history.ui.acls.enable,true) (spark.acls.enable,true)
>   (spark.history.provider,org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider)
>   (spark.executor.extraLibraryPath,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64)
>   (spark.executor.memory,2g) (spark.io.encryption.enabled,true)
>   (spark.shuffle.file.buffer,1m)
>   (spark.eventLog.dir,hdfs:///spark2-history/) (spark.ssl.protocol,TLS)
>   (spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled,true) (spark.executor.cores,3)
>   (spark.history.ui.port,18081)
>   (spark.sql.statistics.fallBackToHdfs,true)
>   (spark.repl.local.jars,file:///opt/folder/postgresql-42.2.2.jar,file:///opt/folder/ojdbc6.jar)
>   (spark.ssl.trustStorePassword,*********(redacted))
>   (spark.history.ui.admin.acls,) (spark.history.kerberos.enabled,true)
>   (spark.shuffle.io.backLog,8192) (spark.sql.orc.impl,native)
>   (spark.ssl.enabledAlgorithms,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)
>   (spark.sql.orc.enabled,true)
>   (spark.yarn.dist.jars,file:///opt/folder/postgresql-42.2.2.jar,file:///opt/folder/ojdbc6.jar)
>   (spark.sql.hive.metastore.version,3.0)

And from hive-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive</value>
</property>
```

Code looks like:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName(getClass.getSimpleName)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
...
dataFrame.write
  .format("orc")
  .options(Map("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc" -> true.toString))
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .saveAsTable("name")
```

Spark-submit:

```
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode client \
    --driver-memory 2g \
    --driver-cores 4 \
    --executor-memory 2g \
    --num-executors 10 \
    --executor-cores 3 \
    --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true" \
    --conf "spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts" \
    --conf "spark.sql.warehouse.dir=/warehouse/tablespace/external/hive/" \
    --jars postgresql-42.2.2.jar,ojdbc6.jar \
    --files config.yml,/opt/jdk1.8.0_172/jre/lib/security/cacerts \
    --verbose \
    component-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
```

Comment: Could you try passing the hive.xml location in the spark-submit as --file command ?

Comment: Can you check the value of `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` and perhaps `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir`? Could you include the Environment tab from web UI in the question? You can always use `hive-site.xml` on CLASSPATH to point to the directory.

Comment: BTW I can't seem to find the version of HDP at https://docs.hortonworks.com/. The latest seems HDP-3.0.1. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Thank you for quick responce, guys. Jacek, this build: http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/2.3.1.3.0.1.0-187/

Comment: How do you access a Hive table? Can you show the exact query (e.g. `spark.read...`)? What's the directory of the Hive warehouse? Can you check all the `HADOOP_`-, `YARN_`- or `HIVE_`-related environment variables?

Comment: Jacek, what Hadoop, YARN and Hive variables I should check?

Comment: Avishek, manual adding of hive-site.xml doesn't help.

Comment: Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this is a not implemented Spark [feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16996). But the only one way to use Spark and Hive since 3.0 that I found is to use [HiveWarehouseConnector](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/spark-llap/tree/master) from Horton. Documentation [here](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.0/integrating-hive/content/hive_hivewarehouseconnector_for_handling_apache_spark_data.html). And good guide from Horton Community [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/223626/integrating-apache-hive-with-apache-spark-hive-war.html).
I leave the question unanswered until Spark developers have prepared an own solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a bit of a throwback trick for this one although disclaimer, it bypasses the ranger permissions (don't blame me if you incur the wrath of an admin).

To use with the spark-shell

```
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf
spark-shell --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf"
```

To use with sparklyR

```
Sys.setenv(HIVE_CONF_DIR="/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf")
conf = spark_config()
conf$'sparklyr.shell.driver-class-path' = '/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf'
```

It should work for the thriftserver too but I have not tested.